# Как изменять url в соответствии с подгружаемыми страницами?

Tags: jquery, url, ajax, history

Подскажите, есть вот такой вот `ajax` код:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("a[rel='footer']").click(function (e) {
            pageurl = $(this).attr('href');

            $.ajax({
                url: pageurl + '?rel=footer',
                success: function (data) {

                    $('.container').html(data);

                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы url менялся на страницу, которая подгружается? Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку такого образца на странице т.о. блок `.container` очищался, а потом в него загружалась информация ajax'ом, при это менялся url. Помогите, пожалуйста, переделать. Довольно много с этим мучаюсь!

Answer (score 2):

Что в вашем вопросе значит url?  Если имеется в виду url ссылки, на которую нажали, тогда всё просто..

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("a[rel='footer']").click(function(e)
    {
        var that = $(this);
        pageurl = $(this).attr('href');

        $.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=footer',success: function(data){
            $('.container').html(data);
            that.attr('href', '_нужный_url_');    
        }});
        return false;  
    });
});
</script>
```

Если имеется в виду другое, тогда поясните вопрос.

Comment: Не работает =(

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите тут:

- [Как поменять url в адресной строке, без перехода на другую страницу](http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=5d0c96151f68ecd1);
- [Смена URL без перезагрузки страницы](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/6436/).

Answer (score 1):

Это можно реализовать с помощью History API, работает не во всех браузерах, [вот статья на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/)